# Webform Price Sets

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, webform-civicrm

I have a ticket page using a Civi Contribution page and a webform. Is there a way to allow price sets in a webform? What I am looking to do is have a series of options, ($5, $10, $20) and then have a donation amount where they can enter any amount in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this by:

- Installing the [webform select or other](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module.
- Changing the price field's widget to a select (by default it is a textfield) and enabling the options you wish plus the "other" feature provided by the above.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM pricesets cannot be integrated with webforms, but you should be able to create various contribution ammounts within the webform which may be sufficient depending on your use case. You may find some interesting information on the topic [in this forum post](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=33728.0) and [as well as in the civicrm wiki](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration).

Comment: I can create various contribution amounts, but I just don't see a way to have a selection of amounts and then another option to put any amount in. That is where I am stuck.

Comment: If this is done, CiviEvent/CiviCRM can't be used for changing registration status, partial payments, etc. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Which versions of Civi / Drupal are you on?

I'd have thought you could do this through the webform integration api? Under the CiviCRM tab if you enable "contribution", is there an option for price set there?

Incidentally, why use webform here, and not the CiviCRM contribution page (sorry if I misunderstood)?

Comment: I don't see an option there. I can see that you can add a select list of prices, but I am not sure how to add an additional amount field. The only reason we are using webform is because we need the confirmation email in an html format as we need to embed a ticket image in it. Or we could attach it, but I don't think Civi confirmation email is capable of HTML or attachments. Otherwise we would go that route.

Comment: We just updated our Civi and Drupal, so we are on the latest versions of each.

Comment: You may be able to use CiviRules here - on contribution, send email of a certain template, which would let you use HTML. I'm not sure about attachments though. Is the ticket image created individually for each user, or is it the same across all mails that get sent?

Comment: The ticket image is the same for everyone. I have not used Civi Rules at all..is that difficult to set up?

Comment: No, not at all. You can install it as an extension and it is configured through an interface - no code required! The only issue is that, as CiviRules is a fairly new extension, it may not work perfectly, in which case you may need some custom development.

If you'd like my help email me at john@civifirst.com.