# Adding additional admin fee on top of civicontribute membership signup

Tags: civicontribute

I need to create a membership signup price with the following price:

Membership Fee: £500.00 + Vat and Administration fee: £20 + Vat

I manage to add the membership fee and vat but I could not figure out how to set additional admin fee and vat.

Can anyone please help me how I can achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't tried using priceset then i would recommend you to use priceset

The best way to have membership fee and administration fee would be using a price set which allows you to have multiple option

reference: 
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Membership+Price+Sets

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/membership/membership-price-sets/

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: thanks Ramesh. is it possible to show that priceset in the civicrm webform. I have multiple page break in the form and priceset is not showing in the contribution section. thanks in advance

Comment: please refer to webform priceset : http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10118/webform-price-sets

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are on Civi 4.7+, but the instructions for VAT can be found at the following link: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/contributions/sales-tax-and-vat/

If you have followed these instructions and this is what you are having issue with, please edit your question to include a screen shots of the price set and field options - that might help us understand the issue you are facing at the moment.

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Comment: Hi Tamar, thank you for your comment. I can add the VAT on the membership price but I also need to add administration fee. And need to add vat on that fee as well. And that admin feed needs to be shown in the membership form. Can you let me know if that could be possible. Thanks in advance.